# How to set Foreign key to custom user model in CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have this custom user model 'es_user'

**models.py**

```
class es_user(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class es_event(models.Model):
    ev_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ev_venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ev_admin =  models.ForeignKey('es_user',related_name='events',on_delete=None)
```

Eventually, I'll be adding more fields to es_user that's why I used a custom user model. So I cannot settle for django's inbuilt user model.

**views.py**

```
class CreateEventView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = es_event
    fields = ['ev_name','ev_venue','ev_date','ev_description']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.ev_admin = self.request.user
        return super(CreateEventView, self).form_valid(form)
```

when I submit the form I get this error

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: randy>>": "es_event.ev_admin" must be a "es_user" instance.
```

I've checked Django documentation and other stack overflow posts, but in all those the foreign key is referencing Django's inbuilt user model

Answer (score 1):

So just assign the es_user, not the auth user.

```
form.instance.ev_admin = self.request.user.es_user
```

Comment: when I changed it i get this error  `self.related.get_accessor_name()
django.contrib.auth.models.User.es_user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no es_user`.

Comment: Well, that's clearly telling you that there is no es_user for the current logged-in user. Did you create one?

Comment: when I changed the user field of es_user to `user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='es_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` . it worked 
thanks @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the `es_user` instead:

```
form.instance.ev_admin = es_user.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

everything worked fine when I made some changes to views.py and models.py

**views.py**

```
class CreateEventView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
model = es_event
fields = ['ev_name','ev_venue','ev_date','ev_description']
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.ev_admin = self.request.user.es_user
```

models.py

```
class es_user(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='es_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```